# Testing redirections CakePHP 2.0

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, testing, redirect, cakephp-2.0

I have been looking at some examples at the cookbook but i dont get it:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#a-more-complex-example

How can i test a redirection in a delete action like this one?

```
public function delete($id = null){         
        $this->Comment->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Comment->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid comment'));
        }
        if ($this->Comment->delete()) {         
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comment deleted'));
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $idPost));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comment was not deleted'));
        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $idPost));        
    }
}
```

The test stops after the redirect call, so it doesn't even print this echo:

```
public function testDelete(){       
    $result = $this->testAction("/comments/delete/1");
    echo "this is not printed";
    print_r($this->headers);        
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it's throwing an empty view error. You can try mocking the `render` function on the controller in this case, since there's no delete view anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by mocking it? And yeah, there no, the redirection works fine and the view action is not empty.

Comment: Mocking is a procedure in testing where you make certain methods return what you want. For example, `CakeRequest::send()` is mocked and told to do nothing, so that it doesn't send headers. You can even tell mocked methods what to expect or how to respond (see: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html). For easy mocking with Cake, check out: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#using-mocks-with-testaction. `ControllerTestCase::testAction()` does some of this automatically for you.

Comment: I have been trying it but i dont get it work. Wouldn't it be more simple to do something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986907/can-cakephps-testaction-method-survive-a-redirect-call

Comment: That could *significantly* change the behavior of your code. I'll put together a proper answer in a minute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Testing your delete action should be relatively the same as testing any other action. Your test case might look something like this.

```
// notice it extends ControllerTestCase
class PostsControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

    function testDelete() {
      $this->testAction('/posts/delete/1');
      $results = $this->headers['Location'];
      // your OP code redirected them to a view, which I assume is wrong
      // because the item would be deleted
      $expected = '/posts/index';
      // check redirect
      $this->assertEquals($results, $expected);

      // check that it was deleted
      $this->Posts->Post->id = 1;
      $this->assertFalse($this->Posts->Post->exists());
    }

}
```

Of course, this just checks the obvious. You can also check the session and write a test that expects the exception. If it's still not reaching the end of the test case or continuing on, **something else is going on**.

You can generate easy mocks by using the `generate` method on `ControllerTestCase`.

```
function testDelete() {
  $Posts = $this->generate('Posts', array(
    'components' => array(
      'Email' => array('send'),
      'Session'
    )
  ));
  // set ControllerTestCase to use this mock
  $this->controller = $Posts;

  $this->testAction('/posts/some_action_that_sends_email');
}
```

The above would first generate a mock of the PostsController to use during testing. It also mocks the `send()` method on the EmailComponent, and the entire SessionComponent.

For more information on mocking: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html

For more information on `generate()`: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#using-mocks-with-testaction

Comment: After this call:  $this->testAction('/posts/delete/1'); nothing is executed. So i can not even do $results = $this->headers['Location'];

The redirect stops it.

Comment: It sounds like something else is happening, then. Try posting your full test case, scatter some debug statements in the `delete()` action, check it with another action that uses redirect, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Possible you have an error because `$idPost` is undefined.

I would write something like this:

```
public function delete($id = null){         
        $this->Comment->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Comment->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid comment'));
        }
        if ($this->Comment->delete()) {         
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comment deleted'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comment was not deleted'));
        }
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $id));        
    }
}
```

And test it's like this:

```
public function testDeleteWithSuccess() {
        $Controller = $this->generate('Comments', array(
            'components' => array(
                'Session'
            ),
            'models' => array(
                'Comment' => array('exists')
            )
        ));

        $Controller->Comment->expects($this->once())
            ->method('exists')
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));

        $Controller->Session->expects($this->once())
            ->method('setFlash')
            ->with('Comment deleted');

        $this->testAction("/comments/delete/ID");

        $this->assertEquals($this->headers['Location'], 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/posts/view/ID');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The echo never be printed, your function "delete" always calls a redirect before ends.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function delete($id = null){         
    $this->Comment->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Comment->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid comment'));
    }
    if ($this->Comment->delete()) {         
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comment deleted'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Comment was not deleted'));
    }
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $id));        
}
```

}

Plenix,
Isn't that totally wrong?
You are deleting a comment and passing the comment's id to the post's view controller ? So, you're viewing the post or the comment by doing so?? Any other suggestion ?